# Objective C, C++ and sending messages from a view controller to app dlegate

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c

I have a C++ module I am using in my AppDelegate class. This all works fine. Now I need to talk to my appDelegate from my viewController, and this is causing problems.

I cannot include AppDelegate in my ViewController class and use **[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]**. If I try, compiler goes berserk when it reaches c++ included in AppDelegate. If I rename my ViewController to .mm then it tries to parse AppDelegate.mm as c++.

Is there a way around this? Can I somehow dispatch an event from my ViewControler?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the C++ bit in

```
#ifdef __cplusplus__
...
#endif
```

Or rename the view controller source file from .m to .mm. Then it will be compiled as Objective C++.

Comment: corr: that's `__cplusplus`. also, ifdeffing in/out can be dangerous, depending how the c++ class is actually used. of course, it is fine in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

> If I rename my ViewController to .mm then it tries to parse AppDelegate.mm as c++.

that's not right. by default, the translation should (in this case) be treated as objc++. have you overridden this default behavior? i say this because i use a ton of objc++ -- it works/builds well.

anyhow... let's assume you have to work around this (which you shouldn't). this is useful because it can be better to abstract c++ from other sources (which may not be translated as c++ or objc++).

```
MONObject.h
/* our c++ class.
   use a forward declaration so the c/objc translations don't
   need to see the declaration of t_mon_object_data.
*/
struct t_mon_object_data; 

@interface MONObject : NSObject
{
    /* similarly, use a pointer as an ivar so the c/obj translations do not need
       to see the declaration of t_mon_object_data.
       use new/delete in your implementation of MONObject (which is objc++)
    */
    t_mon_object_data* objectData;
}

- (void)manipulateTheDataWithThisString:(NSString *)string;

@end

MONObject.mm
@implementation MONObject

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (nil != self) {
        objectData = new t_mon_object_data;
        if (0 == objectData) {
            [self release];
            return nil;
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    delete objectData;
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)manipulateTheDataWithThisString:(NSString *)string
{
    objectData->manipulateTheDataWithThisString(string);
}

@end
```

now objc clients may use via `-[MONObject manipulateTheDataWithThisString:]`. of course, you can always use C wrappers, if you prefer.

Comment: that's not right. by default, the translation should (in this case) be treated as objc++. have you overridden this default behavior? i say this because i use a ton of objc++ -- it works/builds well.

Comment: that's not right. by default, the translation should (in this case) be treated as objc++. have you overridden this default behavior? i say this because i use a ton of objc++ -- it works/builds well. I am sure it does. I know people do this all the time. But if I try to include appDel.mm in ViewCtrl.m (where .mm includes Some.cpp) i get errors in CAStreamBasicDescription.h. if i rename ViewCtrl.m to ViewCtrl.mm the compiler gives tonnes of errors saying that this that and the other in AppDel.mm is forbidden by ISO C++.

Comment: maybe it's a typo - are you really including appDel.**mm** in ViewCtrl.m?

Comment: you can verify the dialect by viewing the build transcript of the file. example: `/Xcode3/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -x c++ -arch x86_64 ` where `-x c++` specifies the language/dialect used for translation (c++ in this example). if the compiler encounters valid c/objc which is invalid in a objc++ translation, then you'll have to hide or correct the program (e.g., properly typecast implicit conversions which may be accepted in C). sometimes you also have to change language standards used. (cont)

Comment: (cont) for example, variable length arrays are allowed only as a gnu extension in c++ -- although i don't think they'll be formally introduced to c++.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project settings and try to change the 'Compile Sources As' to Objective-C++